# Explain reason for "not an answer" flag

Tags: feature-request, flags, answers, not-an-answer

This is about my following *declined* but *helpful* flag.

[image: declined but helpful]

**History:**

I saw an answer which almost copy-pasted another answer and I decided to flag that.

In my first flag, I chose `not an answer` option, as it was the closest. Also I try to avoid choosing `in need of moderator intervention` because I already received, "*Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster.*"

The first flag was declined with a common reason. But when I explained in a second flag with `in need of moderator intervention` (which was the only option to give an explanation). That flag turned out be *helpful*.

**Feature Request:**

Is it possible to add some feature(s) to ease the flagging of duplicated answer?

Note: I can think of two options:

1. A `duplicate answer` option to go with the original/first answer.
2. An optional text box for description in `not an answer` option.

Comment: This will likely come down to site culture.  For Arqade, we explicitly do not want flags about duplicate answers; use your downvotes, and let the low quality review queue take care of it.  SO may be different, though, so this might be better asked there.

Answer (score 8):

In your case, I think the NAA flag was wrong, because the answer was an actual answer, albeit a copy/pasted one. Hence the declined flag.

I believe the "in need of moderator intervention" with a proper explanation is still the better choice. In the case where an answer would be fully plagiarized, without any minor modification, then an hypothetical "Plagiarized Answer" flag would be just as good, but in cases where a dishonest user would plagiarize an answer, but modified it slightly to avoid a simple text comparison check, then it becomes a judgment call from the moderator. Thus, the moderator intervention needed flag sounds like the correct way to go.